# Scrolling issue when using nested scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement something like Instagram profile view screen.

App Logo in HeaderView of `UITableView`.

Multiple Tabs in Section Header of `UITableView`.

`UITableView` has one cell as container. Cell contains `UIPageViewController` and there are different pages which will be scrolling as per tabs selection.

Now the pages will be different `UIViewControllers` where it can be any dynamic content like `UIScrollView`, `UICollectioView`...

I am facing issues for scrolling. It doesn't give seamless experience as Instagram Profile screen, Google Maps contributions screen.

How to manage such scrolling that when scrolling initially:
- Full screen should be scrolled till the header logo is not visible
- Once logo is not visible and there is content scrollable inside any page then it should scroll.

[Sample Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MXL1uo8DnCpOFslbT5hk9-K0d4BHMH_Q)